# Regex + vs *. What is the standard?

Tags: regex

I use regex quite a bit for find and replace, and I want to use best practices as much as possible.

I understand the difference between the `+` and the `*` characters. [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) `*` will find all the matches for specified phrase, and `+` will find all but the last instance of the specified phrase.

That being said, when I look up regex phrases on the internet, I see a lot of people using `+` where I feel they could be using `*`. Is the standard to use `+` instead of `*` on generic regex phrases or is there some convention I am missing?

Comment: I *think* you are misunderstanding the difference between `+` and `*`, but could you please provide some examples of what you think their effect is?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got your definitions for `*` and `+` from but they don't look right to me.  `*` means zero or more of the preceding thing, `+` means one or more, and both will gobble as much as they can while still allowing the expression as a whole to match.

Comment: if I have the string "asdf1 asdf2 asdf3" and I am finding '(asdf\d\s)+' it will match "asdf1 asdf2" but if I am finding '(asdf\d\s)*' then it should return "asdf1 asdf2 asdf3". Or if I'm understanding zzzzBov's answer correctly then if i am searching for '(asdf)+' in "asdf" then it won't match anything, while if I'm searching "asdfasdf" it will match the whole thing.

Comment: Why the down votes? This seems like a question worth answering because the OP doesn't know the answer

Comment: Both `(asdf\d\s)+` and `(asdf\d\s)*` will match the substring "`asdf1 asdf2 `" (including the space after `asdf2`).  They won't include `asdf3` because the expression in parentheses requires exactly one whitespace character after the number.

Comment: @sparks: Neither is completely correct. `(asdf\d\s)+` will not find `asdf3` because there is nothing to match by the `\s` - but the same should apply when using `(asdf\d\s)*`. As for the second interpretation, searching for `(asdf)+` in `asdf` should return `asdf` (cf. zzzzBov's answer - `+` will match if the string `asdf` appears *one or more times*).

Comment: _I use regex quite a bit for find and replace, and I want to use best practices as much as possible._ If you _really_ want to use best practices with regex, go read: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!") (You can thank me later.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you've linked to is great, but you're misunderstanding the definitions of `*` and `+`. Essentially, `*` means "zero or more," `+` means "one or more."

In other words:

- `X*` means "any number of `X` characters in a row, **or possibly none at all.**"
- `X+` means "any number of `X` characters in a row, but **at least one.**"

So `X+` is equivalent to `XX*` (or even `X*X`). They both have an infinite upper limit, but different lower limits.

As far as which one is standard/best practice, the answer is "neither," since they both have different meanings. However, if you're trying to match one or more of something, it's better to use `X+` than `XX*`. Both are correct, but the first is shorter and more readable.

Comment: All good answers, but this one spells it our for me not just informs of the difference. Thanks for the examples and showing the equivalent phrases, that's what made it clear!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you have the proper concept of what those characters mean.  The `*` simply means to match the specified preceding item (usually a single character, character class, or parenthesized subpattern) 0 or more times.  This means you could have any number of occurrences of that item in the string you are matching.

`+` does almost exactly the same thing except the character/subpattern must happen 1 or more times.

So the difference is:

```
* - match 0 or more times
+ - match 1 or more times
```

There is no best practice, as each should be used as appropriate.

Comment: So, compiling thoughts from the different solutions here, so correct me if I'm wrong. If I am using the regex 'asdf[0-9]+' it will match  'asdf0' but not 'asdf' and if i was using the regex 'asdf[0-9]* it would match both 'asdf0' AND 'asdf' right?

Comment: @sparks That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are different depending on which language it's used in, but it appears that you're using the wrong definitions for `*` and `+`.

`*` is the same as `{0,}` (zero or more times)
`+` is the same as `{1,}` (one or more times)

Comment: If he doesn't understand `*` or  `+`, he probably won't understand `{0,}` or `{1,}` either.

Answer (score 0):

"Is the standard to use + instead of * on generic regex phrases or is there some convention I am missing?"

No and no. Some people write bad regex, some people don't need to make a distinction, some people get it right. There's no special convention to abide by.

As zzzzBov has pointed out, however, your understanding of what * and + mean appears to be incorrect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In standard regular expressions, `+` means "one or more of the preceding token", whereas `*` means "zero or more of the preceding token".

`[0-9]+`, for example, means "one or more digits".

`[0-9]*`, on the other hand, means "zero or more digits".